# finding min S such that integral is greater than some value

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

I have this function $R(r)$, and $r*R^2$ is a probability density function.

```
R[n_, l_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[(n - l - 1)!/(2*n*((l + 1)!)^3)]*(2/(n*a))^(l + 1/2)*
   D[LaguerreL[n + l, (2*r)/(n*a)], {r, 2*l + 1}]*r^l*Exp[-r/(n*a)]
```

I am basically trying to find the value of $s$ such that the integral of the function $R(r)$ as $r$ goes from $0$ to $s$ is $95\%$ probability.

In the function below, I need the argmin $s$ such that the integral value is at least $0.95$. Solve didn't work for an exact number. How do I set it up to solve for "at least" 0.95?

```
Solve[Integrate[(r*R[1, 0, r])^2, {r, 0, s}] == 0.95, s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integrate[(r*R[1, 0, r])^2, {r, 0, s}] /. s -> σ*a // FullSimplify
(*    1 + E^(-2σ) (-1 - 2σ (1 + σ))    *)

FindRoot[% == 0.95, {σ, 3}]
(*    {σ -> 3.1479}    *)
```

In one line:

```
FindRoot[Integrate[(r*R[1, 0, r])^2, {r, 0, σ*a}] == 0.95, {σ, 3}]
(*    {σ -> 3.1479}    *)
```

Comment: Or as analytical Root expression:  `Solve[Integrate[(r*R[1, 0, r])^2, {r, 0, \[Sigma]*a}] == 
  95/100, \[Sigma], Reals] `  yields `{{\[Sigma] -> 
   Root[{-20 + E^(2 #1) - 40 #1 - 40 #1^2 &, 
     3.14789681093599487090}]}} `

Comment: @Akku14 isn't the `Root` object just a camouflaged `FindRoot` in practice?

Comment: It's great. Did we just get lucky that the ```a```canceled in that expression? Would it not have worked if ```a``` did not cancel?

Comment: @Frank It's not a coincidence that $a$ cancelled. The integrand looks like a radial quantum wave function ($R$ is the radial wave function and $r^2$ the Jacobian) and $a$ is its length scale. So by [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) the result must be a multiple of $a$.